# How to change the navigationBar color in UIDocumentInteractionController in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController
{
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    return self.navigationController ?? self
}
```

I have tried it using `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black`, still it didn't work.

At best the navBar changes to translucent color of the previous ViewController.

Blockquote

Comment: It looks the issue is not with the setting color, check self.navigationController is not nil

Comment: @guru Nope its not nil, I checked

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69302710/2553730

Comment: @guru didn't help, it still stays a lighter shade of the background. The problem seems to be with the OS tool that's used for viewing PDFs

Comment: you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236056/14642035